# Data Analytics Server 3.1.0 throwing exceptions

Tags: exception, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I am using WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 & WSO2 DataAnalyticsServer 3.1.0.
I have made the following configurations:

1. Enabled Analytics in api-manger.xml
2. Directed it to my DAS Server Port
3. Added DAS_AGENT to log4j properties

The servers started properly
In DAS' management console, I uploaded the APIM_Realtime_Analytics.car
All this was in accordance with :
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Running+the+Product#RunningtheProduct-AccessingtheManagementConsole
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics
docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Quick+Start+Guide

But I am getting the following error:

```
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.request:1.1.0 of event bundle with events 1
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:181)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.request:1.1.0 present in cache
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:166)
    ... 7 more
[2016-10-08 16:05:49,621] ERROR  {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} -  Dropping wrongly formatted event sent for -1234
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.execution.time:1.0.0 of event bundle with events 1
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:181)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.execution.time:1.0.0 present in cache
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:166)
    ... 7 more
[2016-10-08 16:05:49,625] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} -  Dropping wrongly formatted event sent for -1234
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.response:1.1.0 of event bundle with events 1
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:181)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.response:1.1.0 present in cache
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:166)
```

Since the server wasn't getting certain Stream Definitions,
I also tried deploying APIM_Realtime_Analytics_REST.car(from a previous version of DAS) but to no avail. I'm getting similar exceptions for that

How do I rectify this? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [the document you are referring](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics) to, now APIM has its own Analytics Server, which is a customized DAS. So now you have a very few configurations to do to see API stats. That distribution already has required CApps installed too. So you don't need to install them manually.

But, as I understand, you are using a vanilla DAS Server instead of APIM Analytics Server. If possible, please try with that. If you can't for some reason, take the car file from that distribution and install it in DAS. That should solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the pointer. Actually did exactly that a few days back. I couldn't find any link to the configured DAS pack though .. Found it with a little digging on github

Comment: Also, I'm facing a problem configuring the databases so as to get an output on the dashboard. Could you help me out?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049444/configuring-wso2-stats-db
Thanks!

Comment: Official download link is at http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/ 
(Analytics link). I'll have a look at the other issue.